# Why do Chrome & Firefox slowly render my home page using MathJax?

Tags: javascript, mathjax

This is my experimental [site](http://www.begolu.com) using `MathJax`.
I browse it using Chrome, Firefox, and IE.
I notice that IE renders slowly. But Chrome and Firefox do more slowly. :-)

Is there any secret tip to speed up the rendering?

## Edit 1

I am still uploading the MathJax using FileZilla now to the remote server.
It needs much time to complete.

Even I use my development machine as a server with MathJax libraries installed, the result is the same as what I did above in remote server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your site is returning 404 requests for these files:

- http://www.begolu.com/MathJax/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/otf/MathJax_Size4-Regular.otf
- http://www.begolu.com/MathJax/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/otf/MathJax_Main-Regular.otf-
- http://www.begolu.com/MathJax/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/otf/MathJax_Math-Italic.otf
- http://www.begolu.com/MathJax/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/otf/MathJax_Size1-Regular.otf
- http://www.begolu.com/MathJax/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/otf/MathJax_Main-Bold.otf

Look at the net tab with [Firebug](http://getFirebug.com)

Comment: I am new to javascript. Could you give me more detailed hint what I should do next?

Comment: It has nothing to do with JavaScript. It is giving 404's meaning it can not find the files.

Comment: I unpacked the MathJax as is without any modification. I will ask the maintainer.